# How can I hide navigation bar in nvim

Tags: neovim, navigation, lsp

I would like to know how I can remove this navigation bar or at least fix that fat red arrow.

Here is my nvim config https://github.com/victororlyk/nvim_config

[image]

Comment: Wecome to Vim! :-). Your configuration is already quite complex. In order to let others helping you it would be nice to you if you could reduce it.

Comment: thanks) lspsaga is creating that bar https://github.com/victororlyk/nvim_config/blob/main/lua/orlyk/plugins/lsp/lspsaga.lua

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay i found the problem it was lspsaga plugin
for some reason the symbol for separator is much bigger in my vim. I have just disabled symbol_in_winbar alltogether.

```
  symbol_in_winbar = {
    enable = false,
  },
```

I have fixed it in this commit if someone is interested.
https://github.com/victororlyk/nvim_config/commit/914cc00dd33ad22d2fad5ec10f355aea7ad77b37